# docker py and build and push AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'push'

Tags: docker

How does one use docker py to build and push to a server?

```
    docker_path = "/path/to/dockerfile/puredocker"
    build_image = docker_client.images.build(path=docker_path,tag=tag)
    image = build_image[0]
    print ('build_image:',build_image)

    for line in image.push(registry_name, stream=True):
        print (line)
```

Is my image not this?

```
build_image: (<Image: 'testme:latest'>, <itertools._tee object at 0x10d9d0ec8>)
```

Hence: image = build_image[0]

```
for line in image.push(registry_name, stream=True):
     AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'push'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `get` method.

```
   docker_path = "/path/to/dockerfile/puredocker"
   client.images.build(path=docker_path, tag=tagged)
   image = client.images.get(<the name of the image>)
   print(image.short_id)
   client.images.push('registry/registry', tag=tagged)
```

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html?highlight=push#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.get